# Counting number of checkboxes in one column of a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to read the number of selected rows in a gridview with javascript. To do this I want to count the number of checked checkboxes in the select column. Currently the columns of my gridview are set up like this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectedBox" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectedBox0" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="SelectHeader" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="CheckBoxes" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="WSUID" HeaderText="WSUID"
            SortExpression="WSUID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
            SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" 
            SortExpression="FullName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MailAddress1" HeaderText="Mailing Address" 
            SortExpression="MailAddress1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MailAddress2" HeaderText="Mail Address 2" Visible="false"
            SortExpression="MailAddress2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MailCity" HeaderText="City" 
            SortExpression="MailCity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MailState" 
            HeaderText="State" 
            SortExpression="MailState" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MailZip" 
            HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="MailZip" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RegistrationSession" HeaderText="Session Info" 
            SortExpression="RegistrationSession" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Guests" HeaderText="CountGuest" 
            SortExpression="Guests" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalOwed" 
            HeaderText="ToChai" SortExpression="TotalOwed" 
            ControlStyle-BorderStyle="NotSet" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPaid" HeaderText="ToPai" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TotalPaid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Balance" HeaderText="BalDu" 
            SortExpression="Balance" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsInternational" 
            HeaderText="International Student" SortExpression="IsInternational" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SessionNumber" HeaderText="Session Number" 
            SortExpression="SessionNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="SLName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" Visible="False" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="NameAddressed" HeaderText="Name Addressed" 
            SortExpression="NameAddressed" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="CancelReservation" HeaderText="Cancel Reservation" 
            SortExpression="CancelReservation" ReadOnly="false" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CommunicationPreferrence" 
            HeaderText="Communication Preference" 
            SortExpression="CommunicationPreferrence" />
    </Columns>
```

Select is the first column. So far I tried to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {

        var numEmails = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
        $("#<%=gvMailMergeExport.ClientID%> input[id*='SelectedBox']:checkbox").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                numEmails++;
        });

    }
</script>
```

To count the number of selected rows but this function also counts another column of checkboxes and greatly throws off the count. Is there any way to just count the number of checkboxes in just one column of a gridview?